# Save Fortran static array for a later run

Tags: arrays, module, static, fortran, save

I have a lookup table as a 4D array in my program which I assemble from multiple input files. It's a pretty large table (> 2gb in size) and I declare it as a global variable in a module. The table values are constant.

I need to tweak different parts of the code and play with some parameters, and each time that I recompile the codes I would have to read those files again. Since it takes a long time at the beginning of each run to open and read those files, I was wondering if there is a way to save this 4D array for later runs.

Comment: The program is currently sweeping through sets of parameters. I am trying new things and making sure that the program is doing what I expect at extreme cases. Previously it was designed to read-in certain set of input files based on different conditions, which made the total runtime much longer. Now with this look up table it is a lot faster. I want to know if the array can be saved and accessed in a .mod file so the module that assembles the array won't need to be compiled and called in later runs, or a similar trick.

Comment: really, if you are assembling from multiple files you may save time simply by saving  that one array to a single file with retrieving with a single read. Binary of course.

Comment: [HDF](https://www.hdfgroup.org/) has a Fortran API, and allows data persistence. It may be overkill for casual use.

Comment: As agent says, just do `write(file_unit) the_array`. Are there any reasons why this is not the right thing? Then you have to tell us why and tell us more about your array, show the code and so on... Alas, you didn't even tell us what type is the array.